# how to select primary index of a table as a column in select command

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table , [Here is my table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiFoZ.png)

my Query `Select * from categories` My question is how i can fetch or echo primary index of my table after executing above query.

`<?php echo "Primary field is =".$rec['primary_field_name']; ?>`
And the output from same query is as

> Primary field is = cat_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need column name ???

Comment: yes i need column name of primary key + rows from a single select query

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass );
    mysql_select_db( $dbname );

    $sql='select * from `categories`;';

    $res=mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if( $res ){
        while( $rs = mysql_fetch_object( $res ) ){
            echo $rs->cat_id . ' ' . $rs->cat_desc .' '. $rs->cat_status.' '.$rs->cat_image.'<br />';
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result( $res );
    mysql_close( $conn );
?>
```

As I misunderstood your question the following query MIGHT be of interest to you.

```
select `column_name`
  from `information_schema`.`columns`
  where (`table_schema` = database() )
  and (`table_name` = 'categories')
  and (`column_key` = 'pri');
```

Though I don't know of a way to get the name of the primary key within a standard sql query.

You could try the following as an "All in One" solution:

```
select *,
    ( select group_concat(`column_name`)
      from `information_schema`.`columns`
      where (`table_schema` = database() )
      and (`table_name` = 'categories')
      and (`column_key` = 'pri') ) as 'PrimaryKey'
from `categories`;
```

I used `group_concat` in the sub-query because it is highly possible to have a `composite Primary Key` - without `group_concat` you are likely to get an error.

Comment: thanks for answer , but how i will echo my primary column name of same table from this

Comment: Just `echo $rs->cat_id` as what @RamRaider said

Comment: sorry i am not asking about to echo value of cat_id , i am asking about to echo name of primary field or index

Comment: thanks.. it work .. but for records i will execute another query ??

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for get column or value

```
$sql='select * from `categories`';
$query=mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key;//For print column name
        echo $value;//For print value
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to get name of column of primary id i-e primary index

Comment: use **$key** for get column name